# Sass - Get color tones from a color

Tags: sass, colors

I'm trying to get certain tones of a color using Sass but the colors I'm getting are not as expected. I'm following [this page](https://m3.material.io/styles/color/the-color-system/key-colors-tones) as an example, screenshot included here.

[image: Primary color tones]

The primary color is #3a691e. In sass, I get these values from it

```
color.blackness($primary-color); // 58.82%
color.whiteness($primary-color); // 11.76%
color.lightness($primary-color); // 26.47%
```

None of them gave me a value that I was expecting. The color is actually #40 on the scale. Maybe the tone would be `blackness - lightness` roughly equal to 47, I'm not sure if that's how tones work.

I want to get the #90 tone on this scale from the primary color but that's proving difficult too. If I do

```
$primary-tone: color.scale($primary-color, $lightness: 90%);
```

The color is not the #90 tone. `$lightness: 60%` is what actually gives me a color close to #90 tone. I'm sure I'm using the sass color functions wrong but can someone explain me how to get these colors from one another?

What I want is to input a color and sass checks what tone is it on the scale of 0 to 100 and return #40 and #90 of that color. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://razorltd.github.io/sasscolourfunctioncalculator/) and [this](http://scg.ar-ch.org/) will help you.

Comment: Cool tools but doesn't look like they'll help. I'll do more tests and update if I find something.